# Connection code the mongoose with database doesn't work. => mongoose.connection.once()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I have a simple connection code when need to connect the mongoose with a database but it doesn't work.
I can't figure out why?

**First part of code. Import dependencies**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

**Second part of code**

```
//Config Object
const config = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };
//Create express app
const app = express();

//Set URI
const URI = 'mongodb://localhost/name'

//Database
mongoose.connect(URI, config);

//Store Connection Object
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB database...");
});
```

**Errors**

```
(node:16484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\NODEJS\quotes-api-men\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:845:32)
    at C:\NODEJS\quotes-api-men\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:345:10
    at C:\NODEJS\quotes-api-men\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\NODEJS\quotes-api-men\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\NODEJS\quotes-api-men\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1135:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\NODEJS\quotes-api-men\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:344:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\NODEJS\quotes-api-men\app.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
(node:16484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a p
romise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.
html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16484) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a no
n-zero exit code.
```

**Has anyone run into the same problem ?**

Answer (score 0):

It is because the promise returned by `mongoose.connect` is not handled properly. If the connection is successful, it will return a connection object (which means your app is successfully connected to your Mongo database), or else it will return an error which you need to handle using the `catch` block.
So the code will look like:

```
mongoose.connect(URL, config)
.then(connection_obj => {
    // things you want to do with successful connection
}).catch(err => {
    // handle the error or log "err" object to debug
});
```

For more info, you can check out the documentation for mongoose [error handling](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling)

Comment: Thank you @shreeshr for your reply. 

The reason why I got that issue because on my local machine or computer not was installed MongoDB service.

With code everything okay.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred because my local computer is not was install MongoDB service.

After when I have installed the MongoDB service on my local computer that the issue was solved.

Also if someone who facing the same issue to check the service MongoDB, might be not launched in your local machine and you need to launch this service.

Follow the below steps to launch or check launched or not :

Go to Control Panel and click on **Administrative Tools**.
Double click on **Services**. A new window opens up.
Search **MongoDB.exe**. Right click on it and select Start.
The server will start. Now execute npm start again and the code might work this time.